# There is a featured question... or is there?

Tags: bug, design, bounties

In Arqade, the featured tab had a blue square with the number 1 in it, meaning that there is a question with a bounty on it. But surprisingly, it said that there weren't any featured questions at the time, even after refreshing the page three times in a row:

[image]

This is weird since the featured tab has always displayed the correct amount of number of featured questions and caching doesn't seem to be an issue here. So why does the featured tab say there is a featured question even though there isn't, or vice versa if there is.

Comment: Are you still getting this?

Comment: Yes yes I am...

Comment: Not seeing anything there. Looks like caching to me.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Also same problem currently at http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured !